# Dividing some columns in Pandas Dataframe with Stock values with a Variable. First Column is DatetimeArray

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division, stockquotes

### Original Question:
I have downloaded Stock data with yfinance for quite a while where I add the latest data to a previous csv file not to download all data every time.
As a Stock split disturb my calculations and Curves I would like to divide all stock values before the split with a constant called "Split".
I am aware that I can download the complete data again and get it correct from Yahoo Finance but I would like to it manually.
My plan is, first to split the complete Dataframe to two. One before the Stock split and one the remaining. This part is working. Later I would like to merge the two Dataframes again. The first Column is "Date". Then the Columns "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Adj Close" should be divided with the split value and the last Column "Volume" should be multiplied with the same value. Only in the first part of the DataFrame.

Thanks to the comments from @cottontail and @luka1156 I managed to get it working. It might not be the most beautiful solution but it is working.
First I make one DataFrame only with all "Date", then I spit the complete DataFrame in two, One before and one after. In these two I remove the "Date" Column. At this point I could do the math with the DataFrame before the split as it has only float values. After the math operation I appended the part after the split to it and finally I used concat to to the the complete file without "Date" and the file with all "Date".
My code ended up like this. In order to follow what happen I write all files during the process but it might not be necessary.

```
    data = pd.read_csv(stockFile,  header=0)

    if os.stat(stockFile).st_size > 4:
        data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
        
        frafilnavn = stockFile
        print ("frafilnavn = ",  frafilnavn)
        Rigtige = 'J'

        Rigtige = str(input('Er dette den rigtige fil? J/N   *\n'))
        while True:
            if Rigtige == 'J':
                print('Indtast tidspunkt for Aktiesplit yyyy,m,d   ')

                Splitdato = year,month,day = input().split(',')
                Splitdato = datetime.datetime(year = int(year), month = int(month), day = int(day))

                Split = float(input('Antal nye Aktier for hver gamle?  *\n'))
                print("value of Split: ",Split)                 
                all_onlyDates = frafilnavn
                all_onlyDates += '_Complet Stock only Dates.csv'
                print ("All only Dates = ", all_onlyDates)
                data['Date'].to_csv(all_onlyDates, columns=['Date'],  index=0)
                
                df=data['Before-Split'] = (data['Date'] <= Splitdato)  
                BeforeSplitdata=data[data['Before-Split']]
                BeforeSplitdata
                print(BeforeSplitdata)
                
                before_allColumns = frafilnavn
                before_allColumns += '_Before Split.csv'
                print ("Before Split all Columns  = ", before_allColumns)
                BeforeSplitdata.to_csv(before_allColumns,  index=0)
                
                beforeValues = frafilnavn
                beforeValues += '_Before Split only Values.csv'
                print ("Before Split only Values = ", beforeValues)
                BeforeSplitdata.to_csv(beforeValues, columns=['Open',  'High',  'Low',  'Close',  'Adj Close',  'Volume'], index=0)
                
                
                df2=data['After-Split'] = (data['Date'] > Splitdato)
                AfterSplitdata = data[data['After-Split']]
                AfterSplitdata
                print(AfterSplitdata)
                
                after_allColumns = frafilnavn
                after_allColumns += '_After Split.csv'
                print ("After Split all Columns = ", after_allColumns)
                AfterSplitdata.to_csv(after_allColumns,  index=0)
                
                afterValues = frafilnavn
                afterValues += '_After Split only Values.csv'
                print ("After Split only Values = ", afterValues)
                AfterSplitdata.to_csv(afterValues, columns=['Open',  'High',  'Low',  'Close',  'Adj Close',  'Volume'], index=0)             
                
                dfbeforesplit = pd.read_csv(beforeValues,  header=0)        
     
                print(dfbeforesplit)    

                dfbeforesplit_div = dfbeforesplit/Split
                print('dfbeforesplit_div', dfbeforesplit_div)    
                dfbeforesplit_vol = dfbeforesplit_div['Volume']*Split*Split
                print('dfbeforesplit_vol', dfbeforesplit_vol)   
                
                Beforesplit_div = frafilnavn
                Beforesplit_div += '_Before Split divided Values.csv'                    
                dfbeforesplit_div.to_csv(Beforesplit_div , columns=['Open',  'High',  'Low',  'Close',  'Adj Close'],  index=0)                      

                dfdivsplit = pd.read_csv(Beforesplit_div,  header=0)

                dfcorrect = dfbeforesplit_div.join(dfbeforesplit_vol, rsuffix='Volume')
                
                
                print('Corrected values', dfcorrect)
                
                Corrected = frafilnavn
                Corrected += '_Before Split corrected Values.csv'
                print ("Before Split corrected Values = ", Corrected)
                dfcorrect = dfcorrect.rename(columns={'Volume': 'OldVolume', 'VolumeVolume': 'Volume'})
                dfcorrect.to_csv(Corrected, columns=['Open',  'High',  'Low',  'Close',  'Adj Close',  'Volume'],  index=0)  
            
                dfcorrectsplit = pd.read_csv(Corrected,  header=0)
                Corrected = frafilnavn
                Corrected += '_Before Split corrected Values.csv'
                print ("Indlæst fil er = ", Corrected)    

                
                frafil = afterValues
                print ("frafil = ", frafil)
                       
                
                tilfil = Corrected
                print ("tilfil = ", tilfil)
                
                bckupfil = tilfil
                bckupfil += '_bckup.csv'                    
                 
                file_in = frafil #'in.csv'
                file_out = tilfil #'out.csv'
                copyfile(tilfil, bckupfil)



                with open(file_in,  "r" ) as f_input, open(file_out, "a") as f_output : #, open(file_temp, "w") as f_temp:
                    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)

                    csv.writer(f_output).writerows(itertools.islice(csv_input, 1, 500))
                    
                with open(tilfil) as csvfile:
                    print(tilfil)

                    KompletuDato = Corrected
                    
                    data1 = pd.read_csv(KompletuDato,  header=0)
                    print(KompletuDato)
                    data2 = pd.read_csv(all_onlyDates,  header=0)
                
                    resultFile = stockFile
                    resultFile += '_færdig.csv'
                    result = pd.concat([data2, data1], axis=1) 
                    result.to_csv(resultFile,  index=0)
                    print(result)
                    os.rename(resultFile, FinishFile)
```

In the directory I get a file with the same name as I called but with Values corrected. I have also a backup file of the original just in case.
I will try the last comments from luka1156 also but here is what I did.

Comment: `Split` is a string. Casting it to float like `Split = float(Split)` before using it to divide numeric columns would solve the issue.

Comment: Yes thanks @cottontail my mistake. That solved the first error. Unfortunately still the division with Split fails.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new DataFrame with the before and after split values you could just do:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
split_n = 2
dfsplit = df/split_n 
dfsplit['Volume'] = dfsplit['Volume']*split_n*split_n

df1 = df.join(dfsplit, rsuffix='_Split')
```

Comment: Thanks @luka1156
Unfortunately I get this error when trying your sugestion.
Exception "unhandled TypeError"
cannot perform __truediv__ with this index type: DatetimeArray
File: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/invalid.py, Line: 55

Comment: Maybe make sure that before dividing the dataframe you have only int and float as columns, so you could do ```dfsplit = df.set_index('Date')/split_n``` instead of just ```dfsplit = df/split_n```.

Comment: Thanks @luka1156, I get no error when I use dfsplit = df.set_index('Date')/split_n but now the 'Date' Column is moved to last Column. 
The df2=data['After-Split'] = (data['Date'] > Splitdato)

Comment: Thanks @luka1156, I get no error when I use dfsplit = df.set_index('Date')/split_n but now the 'Date' Column is moved to last Column. 
Org:            Date        Open        High  .. Adj Close     Volume  Split
0    2017-01-03  260.299988  260.799988  ..225.361176  2859163.0   True

Now:                 Open        High         Low  .. Adj Close      Volume  Split
Date                             
2017-01-03  130.149994  130.399994  129.300003  ..112.680588   5718326.0    0.5
The df2=data['After-Split'] = (data['Date'] > Splitdato) is like original.
I need the Date for Curves

Comment: @ luka1156 Maybe I can define one DataFrame only with all Dates in Column 1. Then make the Splits before and after and remove 'Date' Column 1 in both. Make the division in the first part and rejoin the two without 'Date' Column and last join with the one with Dates only using concat. I need to look more on it. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Now you could just do ```dfsplit = dfsplit.reset_index()``` and then you can again use the syntax ```dfsplit[dfsplit['Date']>datesplit]```

Comment: You could also use ```df2 = data.loc[aftersplit, :]``` when you have ```aftersplit = [x for x in data.index if x > datesplit]```.

Comment: Thanks @luka1156 I will try the suggested to make my solution more nice.